# Avoid resetting AccessFailedCount by CheckPasswordSignIn in ASP.Net Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, asp.net-identity, identity

This Is My Program.cs :

```
//Options For Identity
opt.Lockout.AllowedForNewUsers = true;  //True Bcz I want Active For All Users
opt.Lockout.DefaultLockoutTimeSpan = new TimeSpan(100, 1, 1, 1); //Its Like Ban For Ever
opt.Lockout.MaxFailedAccessAttempts = 10; //Just Admin Can Increase This For Users
```

And This Is My Login Action For Authentication :

```
Check Username ->
_signInManager.UserManager.FindByNameAsync(model.Username);
Check Password -> 
_signInManager.CheckPasswordSignInAsync(userId, Password, False) 
//False Because I dont Want Increse AccessFailedCount In database for Wrong Passwords
```

Now If Admin Want Report a User(UserId) This Will Happen:

```
_userManager.AccessFailedAsync(UserId); //Its Like Increase +1  AccessFailedCount In DataBase
```

So Now My expectation is that if the admin reports a user 10 times-> user Will Ban For Ever

But Problem Is This : if user login to my WebApi -> This Method _signInManager.CheckPasswordSignInAsync automatic Will Reset AccessFailedCount to 0 ... :(

How to Avoid resetting AccessFailedCount by This Method After one time Succeeded login user

Please Dont Say Its Not Possible... (at last Give Me New Strategy)
my Api Is Ready I need Emergency Help

Comment: Keep track of failed attempts in a custom table or column and write some code to handle that logic.

Comment: @VDWWD do you mean this? `Class CustomEntity : IdentityUser`
add New Column Like This `public int MyCount {get;set;}` ?

Comment: Yes something like that. Then you can have the normal fail count for a single login and the total to ban a user if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe you can avoid resetting this count, however a similar effect can be achieved as follows:

- Get the AccessFailedAcount from the user object before signing them in
- Sign the user in
- Restore the AccessFailedCount to the user object
- Update the user object via UserManager

I've tested the code below which uses a slightly different sign in method than you, but the principle should be exactly the same.

```
            //get access failed count
            var signinManager = HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationSignInManager>();
            var user = signinManager.UserManager.Find(model.Email,model.Password);
            int AccessFailedCount = user.AccessFailedCount;

            //sign user in.
            var result = signinManager.PasswordSignIn(user.UserName, model.Password, false, shouldLockout: false);
            if (result == SignInStatus.Success)
            {
                //restore access failed count.
                user.AccessFailedCount = AccessFailedCount;
                signinManager.UserManager.Update(user);
                //redirect away from login page.
            }
```

Comment: Oh my God Thank youu broo ... You saved my project <3...
I want to accept your answer, but before that I have a question
I feel that the program may be disrupted in the future because:
`await CheckPasswordSignInAsync(reset Count)` And `UpdateAsync(Change Count)`
Can it cause errors in the future?

Comment: I'm glad you got it working. Either sign in method `signinManager.PasswordSignIn` or `CheckPasswordSignInAsync` should both work fine. The important part is retaining the original failed access count and being able to update the user object. These are standard to Identity so I doubt they'll change much (if at all) or cause errors in future.